# CommerceJS - Checkout using PayPal

Tags: reactjs, paypal, next.js, e-commerce, commerce

Hi everyone I am currently working on an e-commerce project where I am building a store, I am currently in trouble making checkout as I use a library called CommerceJS and use PayPal for transactions also I am using [react-paypal-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@paypal/react-paypal-js) npm package although I am not doing well since I am stuck here because I can't make a checkout, any help is welcome thanks.

Checkout Page

```
import commerce from "../lib/commerce";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import Navigation from "../components/Navigation/Navigation";
import CheckoutForm from "../components/Checkout/CheckoutForm";
import useShop from "../utils/StoreContext";

export default function Checkout() {
    const { register } = useForm();

    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation />
            <CheckoutForm register={register} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

PayPalCheckoutButton - Component

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { PayPalScriptProvider, PayPalButtons } from "@paypal/react-paypal-js";
import commerce from "../../lib/commerce";
import useShop from "../../utils/StoreContext";

export default function PaypalCheckoutButton({ product }) {
  const { cart } = useShop(); // Existing cart that contains items inside
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const [paidFor, setPaidFor] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleApprove = (orderID) => {
    setPaidFor(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (cart.id) {
      const generateToken = async () => {
        try {
          const token = await commerce.checkout.generateToken(cart.id, {
            type: "cart",
          });

          setToken(token);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      };

      generateToken();
    }
  }, [cart]);

  return (
    <PayPalScriptProvider>
      <PayPalButtons
        onClick={(data, actions) => {
          const hasAlreadyBoughtCourse = false;

          if (hasAlreadyBoughtCourse) {
            setError(
              "You already bought"
            );

            return actions.reject();
          } else {
            return actions.resolve();
          }
        }}
        createOrder={(data, actions) => {
          return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [
              {
                amount: {
                  value: product.price,
                },
              },
            ],
          });
        }}
        onApprove={async (data, actions) => {
          const order = await commerce.checkout.capture(token.id, {
            payment: {
              gateway: "paypal",
              paypal: {
                action: "capture",
                payment_id: "PAY-51028384J84281644LGFZXJQ",
                payer_id: "VE57TQRTVER5Y",
              },
            },
          });
          console.log("order", order);

          handleApprove(data.orderID);
        }}
        onCancel={() => {
          // Display cancel message, modal or redirect user to cancel page or back to cart
        }}
        onError={(err) => {
          setError(err);
          console.error("PayPal Checkout onError", err);
        }}
      />
      ;
    </PayPalScriptProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix actions.orders.create() which uses the v2/checkout/orders API from the client side , with something server side that uses the old payments API.

Use a single API (current orders or the old payments), and use it from the same place (create and capture from client JS, or both calling a server).

You can see a server demo pattern at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , the functions there will work with react-paypal-js -- you just need an appropriate Orders API backend to call.

---

If you are using the old Payments API instead for some reason, it is not the PAY id but rather the EC token that needs to be passed back and forth, along with the PayerID for the final execute.